# Authorize и AllowAnonymous asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Объясните пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Мне нужно чтобы весь контроллер был доступен только для определенной авторизованной роли, но один метод из контроллера был открыт для всех. Но при применении AllowAnonymous у меня открыто всё для всех.

Как сделать это правильно?

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public class FilesDBController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public FileResult DownloadFile(int id)
    {                
    }
}
```

Comment: как ты определяешь, что открыто все для всех? Приведенный код должен работать именно так, как ты описал

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы всё что внутри контроллера было для [Authorize(Roles = "admin")], а для всех был открыт только метод DownloadFile. Просто я не стал указывать все остальные методы контроллера.

Comment: @Grundy после добавления [AllowAnonymous] я без авторизации получаю доступ к тем методам, к которым не должен. В общем [Authorize(Roles = "admin")] игнорируется.

Comment: ты уверен, что ты неавторизован в этот момент?

Comment: Да, я делал Logout. Мне объяснили: "В этом случае вы должны применить атрибут Authorize ко всем действиям, кроме указанных выше. Если вы поместите атрибут Authorize на уровень контроллера, то он сначала потерпит неудачу без проверки действия. Другой вариант - создать еще один контроллер и переместить это действие туда, чтобы ваш текущий код работал"

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо, моя ошибка, ещё раз посмотрел метод Logout и дошло, что он реагирует только на HttpPost.